# How to get this QTableWidget to display items?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget and I can't get anything to show up in it.

The following appears in the constructor of the main window:

```
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Item1"));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,1,new QTableWidgetItem("Item2"));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,2,new QTableWidgetItem("Item3"));
```

When I run the application, the table widget shows up, but the items do not.

I tried adding `ui->tableWidget->insertRow(0);` before the above code, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aha! I figured out what was going on... I needed to tell the control the number of rows it should have:

```
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Example code:

```
//this will give the present number of rows available.
int insertRow = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();

//insert the row at the bottom of the table widget - using.
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(insertRow);

//After a new row is inserted we can add the table widget items as required.
ui->tableWidget->setItem(insertRow,0,new QTableWidgetItem("Item1"));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(insertRow,1,new QTableWidgetItem("Item2"));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(insertRow,2,new QTableWidgetItem("Item3"));
```